# Firebase JS child added changed and removed

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have `child_added` function but it not update automatically when something removed or changed.
How I can do child added removed and changed in one function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "child_removed" event? It's normal to use an event listener for each of the four events; added, changed, moved and removed, not one combined.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#child-removed

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
function handleEvent(event, snapshot, optionalPreviousChildKey) {
  switch (event) {
    case "child_added": ...
      break;
    ...
  }
}
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, previousChildKey) { handleEvent("child_added", snapshot, previousChildKey); })
ref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot, previousChildKey) { handleEvent("child_changed", snapshot); })
ref.on("child_moved", function(snapshot, previousChildKey) { handleEvent("child_moved", snapshot, previousChildKey); })
ref.on("child_removed", function(snapshot) { handleEvent("child_removed", snapshot); })
```